# C++ target throws error with simple grammar T.g

Tags: c++, antlr

I'm trying to target Cpp with a simple grammar T.g outputting to an AST with a tree grammar.

Can't find AST.stg, which doesn't exist in the source code.  Same error with both 3.4 and 3.5 rc1.

Thanks for any help.

```
java -jar ../../../antlr-3.5-rc-1-complete.jar T.g TWalker.g

error(10):  internal error: T.g : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such group file:   
    org/antlr/codegen/templates/Cpp/AST.stg
org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupFile.<init>(STGroupFile.java:69)
org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupFile.<init>(STGroupFile.java:48)
org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadTemplates(CodeGenerator.java:222)
org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.genRecognizer(CodeGenerator.java:283)
org.antlr.Tool.generateRecognizer(Tool.java:661)
org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:474)
org.antlr.Tool.main(Tool.java:98)
```

Comment: I suspect that C++ support in ANTLR3 is very limited. The [repository folder for CPP templates](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/tree/master/tool/src/main/resources/org/antlr/codegen/templates/Cpp) lacks the expected "AST.stg", "Dbg.stg", and other templates seen in [Java](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/tree/master/tool/src/main/resources/org/antlr/codegen/templates/Java), [C](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/tree/master/tool/src/main/resources/org/antlr/codegen/templates/C), and [CSharp3](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/tree/master/tool/src/main/resources/org/antlr/codegen/templates/CSharp3).

Answer (score 5):

The C++ target does not support AST creation (yet).

See: **Unsupported features** at https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2687101